# tizen : The profile that support the sample is not installed

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I am trying to create an app for smart tv with Tizen SDK from Online Single Hellotizen I get the following error "The media profile That the sample is not installed." the Next button and finish are disables so I can not create the project from this template even for you "input device Test" as shown in the screen print below.
Thank you in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You just have to install '**Samsung TV extension**' package using **Update Manager** to development application for TV.
Open Update Manager from:

```
<Tizen-SDK directory>/update-manager
```

Next go to **All Packages** tab > **Extras** > **Samsung TV extensions(public)** > **Install**

[image]

Once installed you would find 'tv' on your profile list.

[image]

Tizen SDK recommends [Oracle JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) . Please make sure you have your Java environment set(not Open JDK).

In Tizen Update Manager go to Configuration and check for the Extra repository Samsung Tizen TV SDK. If that doesn't exists, add the repository:

http://sdf.samsungcloudcdn.com/Public/smart_tv_sdk/releases/samsung_tizen_studio_tv_sdk/stv_extensions_public

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: thank you for your reply I tried to install the extension package for TV I error Installation failed you find below more details on the log of the error  :   Cannot install the Tizen SDK package.
org.tizen.updatemanager.exception.UMException: Cannot install the Tizen SDK package.
   at org.tizen.updatemanager.core.InstallController.wrapExceptionWithGeneralInstallException(InstallController.java:485)
   at org.tizen.updatemanager.core.InstallController.install(InstallController.java:559)
   ........